# Basic Function in React Native

Tags: react-native

I have coded in C++ and C# and Javascript but for some reason I cannot understand the basic concept of a function.

Ive tried all the basic concepts that I am aware, Ive also tried looking online but since this is new to me Im not grasping the concept.

```
class RankScreen extends React.Component {
    foo1 = (message) => {
        alert(message)
    }
    render() {
        return (
                    <View style={styles.chiliView}>
                        <View style={styles.chili}>
                            <Button onPress={this.foo1('Test1')} />
                            <Button onPress={this.foo1('Test2')} />
                        </View>
                    </View>
        );
    }}
```

any one of the two buttons are pressed it should print the message on each one.

what it does is automatically activate the press not on the users input.

but I feel Im missing much more than just a basic concept. such as if I needed to return a value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do the following,

```
<Button onPress={() => this.foo1('Test1)} />
```

This line makes the anonymous arrow function to act as callback to your on press, i.e you are assigning a pointer to a function onPress, if we talk in C language. Then the arrow function is called by using pointer to the function, which in turn calls the foo function.

And in your `componentDidMount`

```
this.foo1 = this.foo1.bind(this);
```

This is for binding this to your function, which will give access to 'this' in your function.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply could you explain to me why i would use each one?

is your second Line similar to a (.addEventListener)?

Comment: @Custard you don't need to use bind if you use arrow function (ES6)

Comment: Thanks for the reply Im seeming to understand a bit better but if say I wanted to access the one button in Javascript I would get by ID and then set the value. How would you go about it here?